Removing nulls from spark Dataframe without using pandas
new_DF=old_DF\
.select(col("id"),
        col("COL1"),
        col("COL2"),
        ).distinct()

new_JSON_DF = new_DF\
  .withColumn("PROP",struct(col("COL1"),col("COL2")))\
.drop("COL1", "COL2")

COL1 and COL2 could have nulls.
If the data is like the following:
id  COL1    COL2

1   null    def

2   abc     null

3   null    null

I want the output in the new JSON DF to be like:
{
   id : 1
   PROP : {
      "COL2" : "def"
   }
},
{
   id : 2
   PROP : {
      "COL1" : "abc"
   }
},
{
   id : 3
   PROP : {}
}


The above dataframe is a spark dataframe and I tried to use this:
new_JSON_DF = new_JSON_DF.withColumn("PROP", map_filter("PROP", lambda k, v: v.isNotNull()))

This is not working. I also tried using the pandas and the following command works for it, but since there is a memory limitation of toPandas function it is throwing a memory error:
pandas_df = new_JSON_DF.toPandas()
pandas_df['PROP'] = pandas_res_df['PROP'].apply(lambda x: {k: v for k, v in x.items() if v is not None})

schema = StructType([
    StructField("id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("PROP", MapType(StringType(), StringType()), True)
])

new_JSON_DF = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df, schema=schema)


Use to_json as follows:
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import struct, col, to_json

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = [(1, None, "def"), (2, "abc", None), (3, None, None)]
schema = "id int, COL1 string, COL2 string"
new_DF = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema)

new_JSON_DF = new_DF.withColumn("PROP", to_json(struct(col("COL1"), col("COL2")))).drop("COL1", "COL2")
new_JSON_DF.show()

# +---+--------------+
# | id|          PROP|
# +---+--------------+
# |  1|{"COL2":"def"}|
# |  2|{"COL1":"abc"}|
# |  3|            {}|
# +---+--------------+

